# Why do particles in a wave medium move (strictly) perpendicularly to the direction of the wave (in transverse waves)?

Tags: waves

I'm trying to learn some physics on my own and I'm having problems understanding waves. I haven't even begun studying electromagnetic waves because I'm stuck with something very elementary, which is trying to understand why particles in the wave medium through which a transverse wave propagates move perpendicularly to the direction of the wave. The reason I don't understand this is the following.

Most examples use a rope, so assume the left end of a taught rope is being move up and then down. My intuition tells me that only the particle that is directly underneath the force that pulls up and then down will move in a strictly perpendicular direction from the motion of the wave. The other particles are adjacent, hence the force should also have an horizontal component that would not allow for a strictly perpendicular motion. So why is the movement of all the particles perpendicular?

Also, why is the movement smooth (i.e. sinusoidal)? Does it have to do with the fact that the source of the wave is an oscillator?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: 1. Could you quote a specific example in question? 2. Perhaps in given problem it is assumed that the amplitude of the wave is small enough so that the movement in other dimensions can be neglected?

Comment: The source of the wave (your hand) imparts the shape on the wave.  In addition, waves represent a form of energy, so as the wave moves down the rope, that energy is conserved such that as the wave passes a given point, pieces of the rope move up and down just like your hand did.

Comment: Thank you Dave, but you are not addressing my question, namely, that all particles except the particle upon which the force is exerted, are also subject to force in the x direction, hence, not completely perpendicular.